# How can I properly access and use the value obtained from a Laravel Livewire 3 event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

In my scenario, I'm listening to the 'update-selected-company' event in a Livewire component, and upon receiving the event, I update the 'company_id' property. The code appears to work correctly. However, I encounter difficulties in utilizing the received value from the event in my JavaScript code. Below is the relevant code snippet:

```
#[On('update-selected-company')]
public function updateCompany($id)
{
    $this->js(<<<'JS'
        setTimeout(() => {
            $wire.company_id = {{ $id }};
        }, 250);
    JS);
}
```

Despite the seemingly correct implementation, the code does not function as expected. How can I effectively retrieve and use the 'company_id' value obtained from the event in my JavaScript logic?

**EDITED SECTION**
I have two components, Create and Company. Create has the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Contacts;

use App\Models\Company;
use App\Models\Contact;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Attributes\Computed;
use Livewire\Attributes\Locked;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Livewire\Component;

class Create extends Component
{
  public $first_name;
  public $last_name;
  public $status;
  public $email;

  // #[Locked]
  public $company_id;

  #[Computed]
  public function companies()
  {
    return Company::get(['name', 'id']);
  }

  public function save()
  {
    $this->validate([
      'first_name' => 'required|string',
      'last_name' => 'required|string',
      'email' => 'nullable|email:rfc,dns|unique:contacts',
      'company_id' => 'required|exists:companies,id',
      'status' => 'required|in:active,in_active',
    ], [
      'company_id.exists' => 'The selected company isn\'t in the database.'
    ]);

    $contact = new Contact();

    $contact->first_name = $this->first_name;
    $contact->last_name = $this->last_name;
    $contact->email = $this->email;
    $contact->status = $this->status;
    $contact->company_id = $this->company_id;
    $contact->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $contact->save();

    $this->reset();

    return $this->redirect(Index::class);
  }

  #[On('update-selected-company')]
  public function updateCompany($id)
  {
    $this->js(<<<'JS'
      setTimeout(() => {
        $wire.company_id = $id;
      }, 250);
    JS);
  }

  public function render()
  {
    return view('livewire.contacts.create');
  }
}
```

The Company component has the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Contacts;

use App\Models\Company as ModelsCompany;
use Livewire\Component;

class Company extends Component
{
  public $open = false;
  public $name;

  public function addCompany()
  {
    $this->validate([
      'name' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $company = new ModelsCompany();

    $company->name = $this->name;

    $company->save();

    $this->reset('name');

    $this->dispatch('close', modal: 'create-company');
    $this->dispatch('update-selected-company', id: $company->id)->to(Create::class);
  }

  public function render()
  {
    return view('livewire.contacts.company');
  }
}
```

Both of these are modals. The Company modal gets opened when a user clicks on Create a company in the Create component when a company they are looking for isn't available in the available companies list. When a company is created the Company modal closes and then I need to update the `company_id` in the Create component to the newly created company and make it the current company in the select tag. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to make this work. Here is how I did it, thanks to [Wizzy](https://github.com/wizzymore) from Github for pointing out that I should use heredoc instead of nowdoc:

```
#[On('update-selected-company')]
 public function updateCompany($id)
 {
   $this->js(<<<JS
     let component = Livewire.getByName('contacts.create')[0]

     setTimeout(() => {
       component.set('company_id', $id);
     }, 50);
   JS);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to update a property called 'company_id' in your Livewire component using a JavaScript event. However, the way you are trying to pass the 'id' value from PHP to JavaScript is not correct. To effectively retrieve and use the 'company_id' value obtained from the event in your JavaScript logic, you can follow these steps:

Emit the event from your Livewire component with the correct data:
In your Livewire component, make sure you are emitting the event with the 'company_id' value when required. You should emit the event when you want to update the 'company_id' property in your JavaScript code.

For example:

```
use Livewire\Component;

class YourLivewireComponent extends Component
{
public $company_id;
public function updateCompany($id)
{
    $this->company_id = $id;

    $this->emit('update-selected-company', $id);
}}
```

Listen to the Livewire event in your JavaScript:
In your JavaScript code, you need to listen to the 'update-selected-company' event emitted by Livewire. You can do this by adding a Livewire listener and updating the 'company_id' value accordingly.

For example:

```
// Assuming you already have Livewire and it's set up properly.

Livewire.on('update-selected-company', (id) => {
// Your logic to handle the received 'id' value.
// For example, you can update some element on the page or perform any other 
actions with the 'id'.
console.log('Received company_id:', id);
});
```

With these changes, your Livewire component should emit the 'update-selected-company' event when the 'updateCompany' method is called, and the JavaScript code will listen to this event and handle the received 'id' value appropriately.

Make sure your JavaScript code is included in the view where the Livewire component is rendered so that the Livewire listener can be properly attached. Also, ensure you have initialized Livewire correctly on the page.

Keep in mind that Livewire and JavaScript interactivity may depend on your Laravel version and configurations, so always refer to the official documentation for the version you are using to ensure the correct implementation.

ok please try this

```
<!-- Your Create component Blade view -->
<div>
@livewire('contacts.create')

<!-- Include your JavaScript code here -->
<script>
    // Assuming you already have Livewire and it's set up properly.

    document.addEventListener('livewire:dispatch', (event) => {
        if (event.detail.name === 'update-selected-company') {
            const companyId = event.detail.data.id;
            Livewire.find('contacts.create').set('company_id', 
companyId);
        }
    });
 </script>
```

and PHP code

```
use App\Models\Company as ModelsCompany;
use Livewire\Component;

class Company extends Component
{
    // ... other code ...

    public function addCompany()
    {
        // ... your existing code to create a new company ...

        $this->reset('name');

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('update-selected-company', ['id' => $company->id]);
    }

    // ... other code ...
}
```

Comment: Let me clarify by providing my full code. I am using Livewire 3 by the way, not 2. And the way you have shown in your answer I think it's from version 2. I have edited my question to give more insight.

Comment: Did AI write that answer? fyi:[Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: To achieve this, you can utilize Livewire's 'emit' method to send the ID of the newly created company from the Company component back to the Create component.

Comment: @sajjadmaneshi I am using Livewire 3 and `emit` is no longer there, there's `dispatch` which I am using and actually, I am getting the newly created Id. If you have noticed, the computed property `companies` is the one I loop through from the frontend to pick a company from. This computed property gets updated simultaneously as the `update-selected-company` event gets fired, that's why doing:

#[On('update-selected-company')]
  public function updateCompany($id)
  {
    $this->company_id = $id;
  }

does not work